# AnyObject vs. Struct (Any)

Tags: ios, swift, struct, any, anyobject

I would like to create a method like this for my projects:

```
func print(obj: AnyObject) {
    if let rect = obj as? CGRect {
        println(NSStringFromCGRect(rect))
    }
    else if let size = obj as? CGSize {
        println(NSStringFromCGSize(size))
    }

    //...
}
```

But I can't because `CGRect` and `CGSize` are `struct`s and do not conform to the `AnyObject` `protocol`. So, any ideas on how this could be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@nkukushkin's answer is correct, however, if what you want is a function that behaves differently depending on whether it’s passed a `CGRect` or a `CGStruct`, you are better off with overloading:

```
func print(rect: CGRect) {
    println(NSStringFromCGRect(rect))
}

func print(size: CGSize) {
    println(NSStringFromCGSize(size))
}
```

In comparison, the `Any` will be both inefficient (converting your structs to `Any` and back, could have a big impact if you do this a lot in a tight loop), and non-typesafe (you can pass anything into that function, and it will only fail at runtime).

If your intention is to coerce both types into a common type and then do the same operation on it, you can create a 3rd overload that takes that type, and have the other two call it.

Answer (score 10):

Use `Any` instead of `AnyObject`.

> Swift provides two special type aliases for working with non-specific
>   types:
>
> • `AnyObject` can represent an instance of any class type.
>   • `Any` can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.

[The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just discovered a much better method of doing this. Swift has a method called **dump**, and it works with a lot of kinds of data.

For example:

```
dump(CGRectMake(0, 5, 30, 60))
```

Will print:

```
{x 0 y 5 w 30 h 60}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to print a `CGRect` or `CGSize`, you could use:

```
println(rect)
```

or

```
println(size)
```

You left a '...' at the end of your function so I assume there are more types that you need to print. To do that you need to make those types conform to the `Printable` protocol (unless they already do). Here's an example of how -

```
class Car { 
    var mileage = 0
}

extension Car : Printable {
    var description: String { 
        return "A car that has travelled \(mileage) miles."
    }
}
```

The you can use:

```
let myCar = Car()
println(myCar)
```

Also, you may want to change the format of the way a type is currently printed. For example, if you wanted `println(aRect)` in the same format as returned by `NSStringFromCGRect` you could use the extension:

```
extension CGRect : Printable {
    public var description: String {
        return "{\(origin.x), \(origin.y)}, {\(size.width), \(size.height)}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's true. But I think "dump" and "NSStringFromCGRect" produces a format that's easier to read. Do you know why?

Comment: Are you using Playgrounds to test your code? I believe your code `dump(CGRectMake(0, 5, 30, 60))` is actually just showing you a preview of the `CGRect` by the playground. Try the code `let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: 30, height: 60); dump(rect)` and you should get the same format as `println(rect)`.

Comment: I have updated my answer to talk about how you could change the format when using `println` though.